# Could I make vinegar from spoiled wine?

Tags: spoilage, vinegar

I have about 20 litres of wine, that was not stored properly (warm place, some access of air), and is now sour.

Can I make from spoiled wine vinegar of the commercial quality? If so, do I need a "mother culture" or just waiting longer will still produce the same quality?

[Similar question, but too detailed for me.](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/4989/cherry-vinegar-was-supposed-to-be-mead) I am asking about the feasibility of the idea.

Comment: Haha yeah that "vinegar" in my story was an accident and probably would not have been usable for anything.

Comment: Some quick googling has yielded: http://italianfood.about.com/library/weekly/aa05100a.htm this has a bit more detail: http://www.honeyflowfarm.com/newsletters/2006/winter/vinegarpage.htm

Comment: You might want to try this question over at http://cooking.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is there anything we can add to the answer here to get your question resolved?

Comment: Woops, thanks, bmike. I left the bottle on a warm place. Maybe soon I should be checking what has come out of it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can make it with a vinegar mother or leaving it alone, with cheesecloth to keep out the flies. If you want a mother, you can get them a lot of places, even Amazon. Wine Spectator (or all places) has a great blurb on it:

> **How do you make homemade red wine vinegar?** [Wine Spectator](http://www.winespectator.com/drvinny/show/id/5023)

If you think it hasn't been hit by bugs carrying acetobacter or another nasty bacteria, you could just put a cheesecloth or handkerchief over the mouth of the container and let it be to see if you get some. My own suggestion is to split the batch up and try a bunch of ways!